# How can I create a non-serializable function in QWIK that avoids automatic serialization?

Tags: javascript, typescript, qwik

I need to prevent certain functions from being serialized in QWIK due to accessibility reasons. Serialization of these functions during download leads to unacceptable delays. How can I create these non-serializable functions effectively in QWIK while ensuring they maintain their performance and functionality?

```
export const ProductFinder = component$(() => {
  const product = useSignal<string>("")
  const nav = useNavigate();
  useStylesScoped$(styles);

  const handleSearch = $(async () => {
    if (product.value.length !== 0) await nav(`/?page=1&categoryType=NEW&filter=${product.value}`);
  })

  return (
    <div class="form">
      <input type="text" class="input" placeholder="Buscar productos" value={product.value} onInput$={(event) => (product.value = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value)} />
      <button class="button" onClick$={handleSearch} aria-label='Search'>
        <SearchNormalIcon size='100%' />
      </button>
    </div>
  )
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make any value and function non serializable in qwik by providing type `NoSerialize` and then using function `noSerialize()`.

```
import { component$, noSerialize, type NoSerialize, useStore } from '@builder.io/qwik';

type Props = {
  someMethod: NoSerialize<() => void>;
}
export const ProductFinder = component$(({someMethod}:Props) => {
  const product = useSignal<string>("")
  const someObj = useSignal<NoSerialize<any>>()
  const nav = useNavigate();
  useStylesScoped$(styles);

  const handleSearch = $(async () => {
    noSerialize(() => console.log("some log"));
    someObj.value = noSerialize(some value)
    if (product.value.length !== 0) await nav(`/?page=1&categoryType=NEW&filter=${product.value}`);
  })

  return (
    <div class="form">
      <input type="text" class="input" placeholder="Buscar productos" value={product.value} onInput$={(event) => (product.value = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value)} />
      <button class="button" onClick$={handleSearch} aria-label='Search'>
        <SearchNormalIcon size='100%' />
      </button>
    </div>
  )
});
```